# Action "makebook/index" does not exist

Tags: routes, symfony-1.4

I have this error, but I created an action class, i think my problem is module generating.
i follow this method.user click the link  automatically redirect homepage.

```
./symfony generate:module frontend article
```

How can i solve this problem?

```
class makebookActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $personalId = $request->getParameter('personal_id', $this->getUser()->getAttribute('detail')->getId());
    $this->personal = Doctrine::getTable('Personal')->find($personalId);

    //if user or his friend viewing makebook showe them all
    if ($this->getUser()->getAttribute('detail')->getId() == $personalId ||
        $this->getUser()->getAttribute('detail')->isFriend($personalId))
    {
      $this->makebook = $this->personal->getmakebook();
    }
    else
    {
      $this->makebook = $this->personal->getmakebook();
    }

    $this->countries = Doctrine::getTable("Country")->findAll();
  }
}
```

My routing.yml:

```
makebook:
  url:  /makebook
  param: { module: makebook, action: index }
most_recent: 
  url:  /makebook/most_recent
  param: { module: makebook, action: mostrecent }
makebook_view: 
  url: /makebook/view
  param: { module: makebook, action: view }
makebook_new:
  url:  /makebook/new
  param: { module: makebook, action: new }
makebook_edit:
  url:  /makebook/edit
  param: { module: makebook, action: edit }
```

This is my stack trace:

```
#0 /home/whatplan/public_html/apps/frontend/modules/main/actions/actions.class.php(84): sfAction->redirect('@personal_homep...')
#1 /home/whatplan/public_html/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(459): mainActions->executeSignin(Object(sfWebRequest))
#2 /home/whatplan/public_html/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(952): sfActions->execute(Object(sfWebRequest))
#3 /home/whatplan/public_html/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(947): sfExecutionFilter->executeAction(Object(mainActions))
#4 /home/whatplan/public_html/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(933): sfExecutionFilter->handleAction(Object(sfFilterChain), Object(mainActions))
```

Comment: can you please include your `routing.yml` and which directory is `makebookActions` located ?

Comment: Hi Manse Thanks for ur reply,here,i poseted my routing.yml.online server project.plz help me.what is the problem.

Comment: What is the filename of your actions file?

Comment: Hi,this is the my action file  class makebookActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->makebooks = Doctrine_Core::getTable('makebook')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->execute();
  }

Answer (score 1):

I reckon from your stacktrace (modules/main/actions/actions.class.php) that the module name is 'main' and so the actions file class should be mainActions - you need to rename either of the className or the moduleName to bring in consistency